# Send text to twitch.tv chat box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send text to the [twitch chat box](https://www.twitch.tv/wtw827) through the console. I am targeting the text area with jquery but can also do pure js.

I have tried the following:

```js
    $(`textarea[autocomplete='twitch-chat']`).text('test');
```

And some other variations. When I inspect the text element, its text is `test`. But the value is not showing up visually, and is also not sent when I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

What is preventing the text from showing up visually, and also sending? And how can I achieve this?

I have also tried stuff like:

```js
$(`textarea[autocomplete='twitch-chat']`).trigger($.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 70}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use `trigger` or other. Just use `val` operator.

This working fine

```
$(`textarea[autocomplete='twitch-chat']`).val('test');
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! I have noticed now that the value changes, the send button won't send unless I use the keyboard to add a character. Maybe there's an event that needs to be triggered?